# Can't get column sizes to match in two Grids, one inside a TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am working on a dialog box in my WPF application.  The dialog contains a number of nested `Grid` controls and a `TabControl`, as shown below.

```
<Window . . .>
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefintion Height="*" />
            <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Name="Common" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefintions>
                <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" . . . />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" . . . />

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" . . . />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0". . . />

                <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Name="Tab1">
                    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                        <Grid Name="Tab1Grid" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column1" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" SharedSizeGroup="Column2" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefintions>
                                . . . 
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            . . .
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                        . . . 
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Other controls here in the second row of the outer most Grid -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The point of all of this is to keep the width of the columns that contain `TextBlock` controls the same, however, it's not working that way.  The `Width="Auto"` attributes seem to be overriding the `SharedSizeGroup` attributes.  If I remove the `Width` attributes from both `Grids`, they're as big as the biggest string in both columns, but that's not what I want, either.  I want the width of the first column in the `Grid` inside the `TabControl's` first `TabItem` to be wide enough to hold the longest string in that column, and then I want the first column in the `Grid` that holds the `TabControl` to be the same size.  Similarly for the third column.

I hope this makes sense.

Can this be done, or am I misunderstanding how the `SharedSizeGroup` feature works?

Comment: You have 2 Grids with the same name ("Common"), so this  either won't compile, or will do something undefined. Is that a typo?

Comment: Probably.  That wasn't cut & pasted but just typed into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not misunderstanding the `SharedSizeGroup` feature. However, to make it work, you must also define a scope so that WPF knows where to look for the shared size groups. To do this, you use the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` property on a container that contains all of the grids that you use the shared size group for. In your example, it would be this one:

```
<Grid Name="LayoutRoot" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

Note that this attached property can be set on any control type, it does not necessarily have to be a `Grid`. 
In your case, you have to be careful, because the TabControl pushes its whole content to the right, so your columns will not exactly align. You'll have to play around with some margins to make it work (the `SharedSizeGroup` will only make the size the same, not the position).

Hope this helps, FYI your code snippet is full of typos, I would suggest running it through Visual Studio first next time...

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it looks as though you want column 0 in the parent grid to be the same width as column 0 in tab 1.  Similarly column 2 in the parent to be the same as column 2 in Tab 1.

If this is the case then give column 0 and column 2 in the parent grid names then bind the width of column 0 and column 2 in tab 1 to ActualWidth property of the appropriate elementName.

i.e.

```
<Window . . .>
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefintion Height="*" />
            <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Name="Common" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="ParentCol0" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" Name="ParentCol2" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefintions>
                <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefintion Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" . . . />
                <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" . . . />

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" . . . />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0". . . />

                <TabControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="1" Name="Tab1">
                    <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
                        <Grid Name="Common" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width={Binding ActualWidth, ElementName="ParentCol0" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width={Binding ActualWidth, ElementName="ParentCol2" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefintions>
                                . . . 
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            . . .
                        </Grid>
                    </TabItem>

                    <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
                        . . . 
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Other controls here in the second row of the outer most Grid -->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: While this is an interesting idea & I will give it a try in the morning, that's effectively what I thought the `SharedSizeGroup` property was about. Oh well, so long as I get it to work, I don't care how it's done.